# JSF custom component missing auto generated JavaScript when used with Oracle ADF

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf, custom-tags

am working on project, where custom JSF component is built and it is working fine in test *.jsp page.

But when this custom tag is used within ADF tag, it's not working. (in weblogic server)

```
<af:showDetailItem ......>
    <af:panelGroupLayout ......>
        <custom:customComp .... />
    </af:panelGroupLayout.>
</af:showDetailItem>
```

Error Details: Custom tag is rendered properly. When ever I click on any button inside a custom component it won't work. I analyzed rendered output of jsp/adf page using firebug. I found auto generated JavaScript for custom components are missing.

Could anybody please point me out why the JavaScript for (only) custom tag is not loaded.

Comment: Can you provide the full page structure, maybe you're missing something!

Comment: @AmrGawish: Here is one more detail which I found today. Above code was working fine against ADF 11.1.1.5, but after libraries are updated to 11.1.1.6 it's not working.

Comment: Did you try to redevelop your custom component in 11.1.1.6 and tried it again with 11.1.1.6 pages!

Comment: @AmrGawish: Custom component is in different project(eclipse). It's probably built using Apache faces implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this reference [this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFUI/ad_custom.htm#ADFUI11215), I believe it should fix your problem